# Запись данных в таблицу базы данных Postgre SQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, sql

Не удается записать в столбец типа char таблицы базы данных символ "/0" (машинный ноль). Пожалуйста, подскажите, как записать?

Answer (score 1):

Такие символы лучше вставлять как chr(ascii код символа)